# Closed form solution to 2nd order trivariate polynomial

Tags: closed-form

Given unknown variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$

And given known constants $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5, c_6, c_7, c_8, c_9, d_1, d_2, d_3$

And three equations of the form:

$c_1x_1^2 + c_2x_2^2 + c_3x_1x_2 = d_1$

$c_4x_1^2 + c_5x_3^2 + c_6x_1x_3 = d_2$

$c_7x_2^2 + c_8x_3^2 + c_9x_2x_3 = d_3$

Does a closed form solution exist? If so, how can it be derived? I am already aware of several iterative methods to solve this, but was hoping to be able to avoid those. Thanks!